# Share folders on dual-boot Wubi and Windows

Tags: windows, wubi, shared-folders

I have a wubi install that was originally ubuntu 11.10, but I upgraded manually to 12.04. My question is how to access files on both OS's from either one. When I am in Windows, I can locate the wubi "hard drive" file, but cannot find anything when in Ubuntu.

For Windows, I have Win7 installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Ubuntu you can find the Windows host 'drive' mounted under `/host`. You can get there by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd>, entering `/host` and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to bookmark.

From Windows you can use something like http://ext2read.blogspot.com/ to access the root.disk (readonly).

I recommend storing data on /host if you want to access it from Windows. It's safer than storing data on the virtual disk.

Answer (score 0):

How the did you get 12.04? And I doubt many people can help you. But in anycase try to install **Samba**. 
For installation of Samba, Open terminal window (Alt+F2 and type: gnome-terminal) and copy the following commands in the Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install samba samba-common system-config-samba
```

When installation finished, Now you need to that folder which you want to share or you can make a new folder.

```
sudo apt-get install samba
```

Note: Then go to Software Center and Search "glade" & "python-glade" and install both of them

Now start the Samba Server Configuration press(Alt+F2 and type gksu system-config-samba). To add a folder which you want to share click on the + button followed by click on the browse button. Now select the folder which want to share on network. Now enter description and check your folder writable or visible settings. Click on the access tab and give access to the user you want, when you finished click on the OK button. Now your folder is added to your Samba Server Configuration.

Now go to the shared folder, Select the folder then right click on the folder and select Sharing Option. Here add a comment and change the permissions for others to create/delete/modification in files/folders and for the guest access rules.

Samba is Sharing service between Ubuntu to other networks (Windows, linux and others).